# Using schemaextender to extend the ATEvent class

Tags: plone

I have used schemaextender to extend ATEvents so that they include a checkbox for toggling the time and iCal display for events.

It works fine on an existing site but when I try and create a new site i get an error "ValueError: nextPreviousEnabled.default_method is neither a method of  nor a callable"

Any ideas? The extension code:

```
from Products.Archetypes.public import BooleanField
from archetypes.schemaextender.field import ExtensionField

class DisplayEventTimeField(ExtensionField, BooleanField):
    """A toggle to indicate whether the view should display the time or just the date of this community event"""

from zope.component import adapts
from zope.interface import implements
from archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces import ISchemaExtender
from Products.Archetypes.public import BooleanWidget
from Products.ATContentTypes.interface import IATEvent

class EventExtender(object):
    adapts(IATEvent)
    implements(ISchemaExtender)


    fields = [
        DisplayEventTimeField("display_event_time",
        widget = BooleanWidget(
            label="Display event time",
            description="Turn this off to show only the event date (also disables iCal/vCal)",
            defult=True)),
            ]

    def __init__(self, context):
        self.context = context

    def getFields(self):
        return self.fields
```

and the full traceback:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 127, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module Products.PDBDebugMode.runcall, line 70, in pdb_runcall
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 47, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFPlone.browser.admin, line 201, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFPlone.factory, line 83, in addPloneSite
  Module Products.GenericSetup.tool, line 330, in runAllImportStepsFromProfile
   - __traceback_info__: profile-Products.CMFPlone:plone-content
  Module Products.GenericSetup.tool, line 1085, in _runImportStepsFromContext
  Module Products.GenericSetup.tool, line 999, in _doRunImportStep
   - __traceback_info__: plone-content
  Module Products.CMFPlone.setuphandlers, line 486, in importContent
  Module Products.CMFPlone.setuphandlers, line 234, in setupPortalContent
  Module Products.CMFPlone.utils, line 306, in _createObjectByType
  Module Products.CMFCore.TypesTool, line 554, in _constructInstance
  Module Products.ATContentTypes.content.topic, line 6, in addATTopic
  Module Products.Archetypes.BaseFolder, line 96, in manage_afterAdd
  Module Products.Archetypes.BaseObject, line 159, in manage_afterAdd
   - __traceback_info__: (<ATTopic at /Plone/news/aggregator>, <ATTopic at /Plone/news/aggregator>, <App.ProductContext.__FactoryDispatcher__ object at 0x1071bfd50>)
  Module Products.Archetypes.BaseObject, line 174, in initializeLayers
  Module Products.Archetypes.Schema, line 338, in initializeLayers
  Module Products.Archetypes.Storage, line 161, in initializeField
  Module Products.Archetypes.Field, line 591, in getDefault
ValueError: nextPreviousEnabled.default_method is neither a method of <class 'Products.ATContentTypes.content.topic.ATTopic'> nor a callable
```

Comment: please post the full traceback

Comment: Full traceback... http://pastie.org/2635646

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/product-developers@lists.plone.org/msg01280.html maybe can give some hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a [browserlayer](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/customization-for-developers/browser-layers) and to implement `IBrowserLayerAwareExtender` intead of `ISchemaExtender`:

```
...
from archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces import IBrowserLayerAwareExtender
from my.product.browser.interfaces.IMyProductLayer

class EventExtender(object):
    adapts(IATEvent)
    implements(IBrowserLayerAwareExtender)
    layer = IMyProductLayer
    ...
```

This ensure that the schema is extended only when your product is installed. Generally speaking it's always recommended to maintain the isolation of customizations to the actual plone instance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I just used the base example from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/archetypes.schemaextender. I shouldn't need to use the browser layer version because it is a custom site on it's own infrastructure (no other Plone sites) and we are happy to have all Events include the checkbox to toggle the time display... doesn't seem to be an issue when you add the Event extension to an existing site, it's just when you try and buildout a new site it throws the error...hitting refresh a few times can get past it successfully or hit a different error so maybe it's a race condition?